# Using "only ever" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

In an old video I found a sentence:

> Despite the tremendous amount of work put into individual pieces, **they are only ever made once.**

Is it the same as: **they are only made once?**

What is the significance of **ever** in this sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the meaning. "Ever" is being used here as an intensifier to emphasize each piece's uniqueness. Literally, it merely asserts the lack of exceptions.